# Why doesn't pandas.Series.replace work to fill replacements?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I'm trying to use an example of replacement of values of a Series in pandas, and the call seems to be performing no action at all.

```
In [43]:  df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4], 'b': [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]})

In [44]: s = df['b']

In [45]: t = s.replace([1, 3], method='pad')

In [46]: t
Out[46]:
0    5
1    6
2    7
3    8
4    9
Name: b, dtype: int64

In [47]: s
Out[47]:
0    5
1    6
2    7
3    8
4    9
Name: b, dtype: int64
```

I would expect that the values would be the following:

```
In [50]: s
Out[50]:
0    5
1    6
2    6
3    8
4    8
```

I'm using pandas 0.17.0 on OSX 10.11.1 in iPython 4.0.0, Python 2.7

**UPDATE:**
Example was taken from "Learning Pandas"  extract [available here](https://books.google.fr/books?id=xpRICAAAQBAJ&pg=PT464&lpg=PT464&dq=learning%20pandas%20replacement&source=bl&ots=ApacgcHxo-&sig=as_S5fVEsEd95lhwpf3oaX7pbRA&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=learning%20pandas%20replacement&f=false):

**UPDATE 2**

It works when creating a series directly, but not when using a dataframe column:

```
In [52]: s = pd.Series([0., 1., 2., 3., 2., 4.])

In [53]:    s
Out[53]:
0    0
1    1
2    2
3    3
4    2
5    4
dtype: float64

In [54]: t = s.replace([1, 3], method='pad')

In [55]: t
Out[55]:
0    0
1    0
2    2
3    2
4    2
5    4
dtype: float64
```

Thanks

Comment: You've misinterpreted the function, the passed values are the values to replace, not the index positions

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I've updated my comment with the full example and book I got it from.. my example was to show what they presented.  Thanks for your help

Comment: The book is wrong, see the [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.replace.html#pandas.Series.replace)

Comment: In order to use the index values you need to access the values associated with the index labels: `t = s.replace(s[[2,4]].values, method='pad')` would work

Comment: The book is calling the values, I don't think it's calling the index. But the output is not right, the padding went beyond the specified values.

Comment: Your second edit is different as your values match the index values

Comment: @EdChum  ahh.... that's why.. thanks.. that makes sense..  (values matching index values)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want the `t` to change not the `s`, correct?

```
In [13]: t = s.replace([7,9], method='pad') #specifying the values that need to be replaced
         t

Out[13]: 
0    5
1    6
2    6
3    8
4    8
```

Taken from [book](https://books.google.fr/books?id=xpRICAAAQBAJ&pg=PT464&lpg=PT464&dq=learning%20pandas%20replacement&source=bl&ots=ApacgcHxo-&sig=as_S5fVEsEd95lhwpf3oaX7pbRA&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=learning%20pandas%20replacement&f=false) but changing values to remove contradiction with index values.

```
s = pd.Series([4,5,6,7,8,9])

s[0] = 10

s.replace([5,6,7],method='pad')
Out[16]: 
0    10
1    10
2    10
3    10
4     8
5     9
dtype: int64
```